# how to get data from related data object on react-bootstrap-table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

bootstrap-table module to display some data on my page and I want to make a link from related data to dataField value, Here's a snippet:

Here's my JSON data:

`{"person": {
  "name" : "jhon", 
  "personLink" : "jhonlink"
 },{
  "name" : "doe", 
  "personLink" : "doelink"
 }
}`

Here's my function code:

```
myLink = (cell) => {
 const urlString = '/person/detail/' + cell;
 return (
   <Link to={urlString} >
     {cell}
   </Link>
 )}
```

Here's a snippet of my render:

```
<BootstrapTable
   data={person}
   striped
   hover
   pagination
   remote
   >
   <TableHeaderColumn
      isKey
      dataField="name"
      dataFormat={this.personLink}
    >
   Foo
   </TableHeaderColumn>
</BootstrapTable>
```

is it possible to get a value from "personLink"? since I got the "name" value as a link.

Comment: Where do you want to extract the personLink value. Also person should be an array right?

Comment: i just edit my question, i want to extract "personLink" into myLink function, as a paremeter (cell)

Answer (score 0):

Considering the person data is in state data as

```
state= {
   data: {"person": [{
  "name" : "jhon", 
  "personLink" : "jhonlink"
 },{
  "name" : "doe", 
  "personLink" : "doelink"
 }]
}
```

In myLink function you can get personLink as

```
myLink = (cell) => {
 const urlString = '/person/detail/' + cell;
 var idx = this.state.data.person.findIndex((data) => {return data.name === cell});
 var personLink = this.state.data.person[idx].personLink
 console.log(personLink);
 return (
   <Link to={urlString} >
     {cell}
   </Link>
 )}

}
```